# How to find distinct values in a list of columns and print them in a single CSV

Tags: loops, csv, for-loop, pyspark

I am have a large dataset to analyze which I need to look at the distinct values for multiple features (Flags).
I am attempting to run a for loop as follows:

```
d= {}
name_list = ["ultfi_ind", "status"]   # Add names of columns here
for x in name_list:
        d["{0}".format(x)]  = test_df.select(x).distinct().collect()   # Please change df name

dist_val = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)
```

Here I am specifying the column names in the name_list list and the then in the for loop I am finding the distinct values in each of the columns and saving the output in a dictionary.

Finally I am attempting to combine it all in a single dataframe but that isn't possible as the length of the columns isn't same.

I am aware that one to do it is via padding but I find that too complex a solution and am wondering if there's a smart way to go about this.

Note that I am running this in a spark environment as my dataset is large.

I imagine the ultimate output to be a single CSV file/ Dataframe wherein the header is the name of the column mentioned in the name_list (above) and underneath that the distinct values are listed.

d= {}
name_list = ["ultfi_ind", "status"]   # Add names of columns here
for x in name_list:
d["{0}".format(x)]  = test_df.select(x).distinct().collect()   # Please change df name

dist_val = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are talking about is data profiling.  There pandas.dataframe has a describe function to start your journey off.

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html#

If you want something a little more graphical, look at this article on towards data science.

https://towardsdatascience.com/3-tools-for-fast-data-profiling-5bd4e962e482

If you want to roll your own, you can.  I am not going to code it for you since you will not learn.  But enclosed is an algorithm that I would use.

```
1 - Get a list of columns and types in the data set. 
2 - If number, we can give aggregations such as min, max, avg, etc.
3 - If non-numeric, we can group by field + count() occurrences
```

All this data can be outputted in as a data frame and save to your favorite format.

Last but not least, there is the spark.topandas library the replaces koalas.  This allows you to convert a spark dataframe to a pandas dataframe to use some of these prebuilt functions.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.toPandas.html

Comment: Thank you so much. The articles were really helpful.
I ended up using:
from pandas_profiling import ProfileReport   #Be sure to install pandas_profiling and dataclasses library
profile = ProfileReport(pmt_df1, title="Pandas Profiling Report")

It generated the output exactly as I imagined it would. I shall keep working on your matrix as part of a larger side project